# How to resolve "." domain for logins

Tags: c#, dns, windows-authentication

When specifying credentials .\localuser can be used to specify a local user. My question is what underlying logic is doing this resolution and can I use it outside of authentication?

System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry seems to resolve everything but the '.' case.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way get the machine name? Or are you trying to get the name of the current user?

Comment: I'm trying to get the machine name. I realize there are ways to get this directly (ex: Environment.Machinename) but I want to translate '.' to the machine name without needing to handle the case myself.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);    // Change ContextType for Domain, or AD
var p = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthenticablePrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, ".\\Mike");

Console.WriteLine("{0}\\{1}", pc.ConnectedServer, p.Name);
```

Comment: That works, but only when resolving users. There's also issues with security (specifically within AD) that searching for a specific user adds.  
I'm looking for something that can take 'localhost','domain.com', 'machineName', or '.' and resolve it directly without needing to go through user resolution.